# Isomorphism Finite Topological Space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Does there exist a finite topological space with fundamental group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2}$?

Answer (score 11):

Yes.  In the paper "Singular homology groups and homotopy groups of finite topological spaces" by Michael McCord [Duke Math. J. 33 (1966) pp. 465-474], it is proved (among other things) that every finite simplicial complex $K$ has its geometric realization weakly homotopy equivalent to a finite topological space.  Apply that with $K$ being a triangulation of the projective plane.